# Eliminar repetidos de un objeto

Tags: javascript

deseo eliminar de un objeto los repetidos, tengo el siguiente objeto:

```js
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true} 
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
{id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false}
{id: 107, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
```

donde id_programa_educativo se repite, deseo eliminar esos repetidos y que quede así.

```js
{id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false}
{id: 107, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true}
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}
```

Intente con .filter así pero me arroja vacio:

```js
array3.filter(x => x.id_programa_educativo == x.id_programa_educativo)
```

Comment: Conociendote me pregunto... eso es javascript o angular+typescript?  Recuerda poner bien las etiquetas siempre, sino nos confundes y todos perdemos el tiempo (nosotros intentando ayudarte con javascript cuando no lo es, y tu teniendo que soportarnos y no entendiendo nuestras respuestas porque no te funcionan en typescript)

Comment: es javascript amigo por eso puse no mas javascript :) si ya me conocen jejeje saludos amigo

Comment: Y que pasa con las otras propiedades?? Si id_programa_educativo se repite pero tuvieran distinto valor en "activo"??? Puedes darse esa situación?

Comment: muy buena obersvacion amigo @Yussef, asi es tienes razon y se me olvido mencionarlo igual si difiere las otras porpiedades pero si el id_ programa es igual igual seria descartar esa parte repetida

Comment: Vaya, pues si es javascript tiene defectos de sintaxis porque un objeto no se representa de ese modo, sino más bien entrecomillando las cadenas de texto `'undefined'`, y si eso forma parte de un array, entonces poniendo comas al final de cada conjunto de llaves `{}` para separar los elementos del array de objetos y encerrándolo todo entre corchetes `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que tus objetos siempre tienen las mismas propiedades, puedes usar filter:

```js
const objects =
[{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true},
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true},
{id: 106, id_programa_educativo: 38, activo: false},
{id: 107, id_programa_educativo: 39, activo: false},
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 40, activo: true},
{id: undefined, id_programa_educativo: 41, activo: true}];


const resp = objects.filter((value, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) =>
        t.id_programa_educativo === value.id_programa_educativo
    )
);
console.log(resp);
```

El problema con tu versión de `filter` es que estás comparando cada objeto consigo mismo, por lo que la comparación devolverá siempre `true` y no eliminará ningún elemento.

Con esta variante, lo que hacemos es comprobar si el índice de cada elemento coincide con el primero en la lista que comparte su `id_programa_educativo`

Comment: Ya no pude comentar amigo perdón, se me fue la luz en mi colonia, pero me sirvió de bastante tú respuesta amigo. gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @oscarggh no te preocupes, me alegro de que te sirviera